# String with UITextVIew.text and label

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uilabel, uitextview

```
self.tweetString = [NSString stringWithFormat:_websiteLabel.text, _detailItem];
```

I have to make a string where the text is from a textView and from a label with a space in between them. Using the following code just shows the text from the TextView. How do I code it?

`_websiteLabel` is the TextView and `_detailItem` is the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand you correctly you would be looking for this:

```
self.tweetString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", _websiteLabel.text, _detailItem.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
self.tweetString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", _websiteLabel.text, _detailItem.text];
```

OR

```
self.tweetString = [NSString stringWithString:_websiteLabel.text, _detailItem.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
self.tweetString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", _websiteLabel.text, _detailItem.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `self.tweetString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",_websiteLabel.text, _detailItem];`
This should fix your problem.